# change chef recipe/cookbook to work with different OS

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe

I'm pretty new to Vagrant and Chef and want to set up a VM using Scienfitic Linux. Most of the cookbooks I've found (ie for Nodejs or Mongodb) are supported by Ubuntu but not SL. Is there a straight forward way to get these already existing cookbooks to work with SL and not just Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First step is to check the 'metadata.rb' file inside the base of the cookbook.  You will most likely see a line similar to the following (this snippet from my [twitter](http://bit.ly/cheftwit) cookbook):

```
%w{ centos redhat fedora ubuntu debian arch windows }.each do |os|
  supports os
end
```

In a nutshell, you want to see your operating system listed (depending on what ohai calls it).  My guess is that SL is going to show up as 'arch'.  Just apply the cookbooks that you want to try to your node and watch the logs for failures.  You will certainly need to make some minor modifications; however, they will most likely be limited to directory structure or binary names.

Answer (score 0):

Official Chef page [here](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Fast+Start+Guide) says:

Chef runs on many popular Unix and Linux platforms as well as Max OSX and Windows. These install directions should work for any of the following operating systems: Ubuntu, Debian, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Fedora, CentOS, Oracle, Scientific Linux and OS X.

And also:

In order to make this as quick as possible, we make some assumptions. If your system does not meet these assumptions, you will need to use the Installation instructions that apply for the "flavor" of Chef you are installing.

Moreover

MongoDB Chef Recipe [here](https://github.com/edelight/chef-mongodb) says:

Platform:

The cookbook aims to be platform independant, but is best tested on debian squeeze systems.

The 10gen_repo recipe configures the package manager to use 10gen's official package reposotories on Debian, Ubuntu, Redhat, CentOS, Fedora, and Amazon linux distributions.

So essentially, it should work on SL too, with minor tweaks IMHO. I am not much aware of SL, but are you facing any error/problem? If you could post what have you tried and what is working/not working, we could solve better!